# How much should I scan an aromatic dihedral?

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, molecular-dynamics

Suppose I have a napthalene-like molecule ([attached](https://www.charmm.org/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=download&Number=1981&filename=dihedral%20scan.png)), and I would like to scan (relaxed) its aromatic dihedral (highlighted atoms). I used CGENFF to obtain its dihedral parameters as follows,

HGA4 CG2DC2 CG311 CG331 0.2000 3 0.00

As shown, the dihedral force constant is 0.2, periodicity is 3, and angle is 0.

However, the penalty factor is high >50. Hence, in order to obtain new parameters and following the typical charmm protocol using MP2/6-31G*, should I perform a full scan +/- 180 degrees? +/- 180 seems unphysical (as compared to a rotatable bond) for a dihedral that belongs to a ring. If so, how much should I lower this value to?

Comment: That is a molecule with far more saturation than naphthalene, but it will still be pretty rigid, so exactly how far do you think it could deform without breaking any bonds?

Comment: @matt_black not very far at all, I suppose. Any ideas?